# Where does ODP.net (managed) create the windows event log message?

Tags: odp.net-managed

[Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/odpnt/featDebug.html#GUID-A1A17BCF-10B2-4A61-8A50-A6CA91CD7CAE) Claim that ODP.net creates a windows event log containing the location of the trace.

> ODP.NET will create an entry in the Windows event log where the trace was created anytime it creates a trace file.

Using the following in my app.config or web.config (depending on whether it's running standalone in unit tests, or in the application)

```
  <oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="*">
      <dataSources>
        <dataSource alias="SampleDataSource" descriptor="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=ORCL))) "/>
      </dataSources>
      <settings>
        <setting name="TraceLevel" value="7" />
        <setting name="TraceOption" value="1" />
        <setting name="TraceFileLocation" value="D:\Oracle_Home\logs" />
      </settings>
    </version>
  </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
```

I am not seeing the log entry being created by ODP Managed data access.

(but did find the trace entry after some effort, can't remember what fixed it)

Where can you find the windows event log claimed to be created by ODP.net? or is this only a feature of the unmanaged client?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/odpnt/InstallManagedConfig.html#GUID-A9EF5624-1828-46DD-84D1-CC5F40BFB6F5

*"Parameters in the version specific section take precedence over the parameters of the generic section. "*

Comment: I don't understand your comment. You seem to be alluding that you can specify version specific options but I don't see how that helps, since I don't have version specific options present.

Comment: "alluding" is of playful character. I suggest that you check if your config is properly formed and sometimes people post their partial code. So that was the tip for such case

Comment: Ah I understand now. Thanks for the tip, but it's not relevant (for me). Hopefully it helps someone else. I ended up finding the configs anyway (without the windows log, so I know it's running correctly) but was still surprised at the seeming lack of info in the windows event log.